# The protocol 'net.tcp' is not supported

Tags: c#, wcf

When I try to browse my service.svc file,I keep getting this error.

1. I've enabled tcp in the default
   website in IIS.
2. The port number 808:* is already
   there in my IIS bindings
3. Ive installed WAS and support for
   non http protocols...
4. TcpChannellistener service and tcp
   port sharing services are running..

But,now why am I unable to browse through the site? It keeps showing "The protocol 'net.tcp' is not supported."

Here's my code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Web.Services.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.IO;

namespace WcfService7
{
    public class clsMyOwnServiceHost:ServiceHostFactory
    {

               protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost( Type t, Uri[] baseAddresses )
               {

                   NetTcpBinding tcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
                   BasicHttpBinding basicbinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
                   WSHttpBinding wsbinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

                   baseAddresses = new Uri[] { new Uri("http://localhost/WcfService7/Service1.svc"),new Uri("net.tcp://localhost/WcfService7/Service1.svc/tcp") };
                   ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(t, baseAddresses);
                   baseAddresses.ToList().ForEach(uri =>
                    {


                        //ServiceMetadataBehavior metabehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();

                        //metabehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                      //  host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metabehavior);
                        if (uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("http://")) host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), basicbinding, "basic");
                      if(uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("net.tcp://"))  host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1),tcpbinding,"tcp");
                       if(uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("http://")) host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), wsbinding, "ws");
                       if (uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("http://")) host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");



                    });

                   return host;
               }

    }
}
```

Please help me...

Thanks so much

Comment: What version of IIS are you on?? IIS6 doesn't support net.tcp in any way, shape or form - you have to self-host. IIS7 / 7.5 support net.tcp, but it needs to be manually activated

Comment: I am using IIS7 and TCP is activated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the port for TCP for your uri. HTTP has a default port but TCP does not.

**UPDATE**

net.tcp is not installed on IIS by default. Make sure it is installed by going to add/remove features and check TCP is ticked.

There are 1001 different settings that must be correct. You need to have an application pool which runs 4.0 so if you have not created a separate app pool, do that and set it to 4.0 and let the application run in that.

**Go to advanced properties for the site and on enabled protocols enter "http, tcp".**

Comment: ive tried adding 808 too....still doesnt work :(...any other stuff that I could try?

Comment: Go to advanced properties for the site and on enabled protocols enter "http, tcp"

Comment: Anything else that I could try?

Comment: old but just a question. shouldn't this be "http,net.tcp" or just plain "http,net.tcp" would still work? i tried the latter before and it didn't work for me before but then again my web.config was faulty before when i tried it.